# Wrong count of users Google Reporting API v3

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I use [Google Analytics core Reporting v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). I request data from Google Analytics.

Request:

```
metrics = "ga:sessions,ga:users"
dimensions = "ga:landingPagePath"
filter = "ga:channelGrouping=@Organic"
precision = "higher_precision"
```

Results

```
{.... // 7 rows with landing pages
....
ga:users: "39"
....
containsSampledData: false}
```

BUT in the Google analytics website I see count of `users = 34` for the same period.

If I delete `dimensions = "ga:landingPagePath"` from request, I get right count of users like in the UI (34 users).

How can I get data with `dimensions = "ga:landingPagePath"` and right count of users like in the UI for the one request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google analytics database is a mulit dimensional database. It is NOT a relational database.

You can not compare things that are not exactly the same.   Create a request in the Google analytics website that has exactly the same dimensions and metrics and date ranges and the data should return close to what you get in the API.  There will always be a few errors especially with calculated columns.

You cant look at two different requests and expect to see the same numbers it doesn't work that way.

**From the Google analytics website**

[image]

**From query explorer**

[image]

**Google Analytics website report**

If you for example want to see this report You are going to have to include all of the dimensions and metrics you can see here in order to get the same results back in the API.  You cant just take Landing pages and sessions and expect the numbers to match up.  This is again not a relational database its a multi dimensional database.

[image]

Also remember to be sure that the dates you are checking are at least 48 hours old.  Data under 48 hours old has not completed processing and may cause your numbers to be off.

For the one you have linked in comments you would need something like this

```
ga:landingPagePath
ga:users
ga:newUsers
ga:sessions
ga:bounceRate
ga:pageviewsPerSession
ga:avgSessionDuration
ga:goal1ConversionRate
ga:goal1Completions
ga:goal1Value
```

Comment: But how does GA show total of users for dimension "ga:landingPagePath" on Google analytics website? [example](https://prnt.sc/l702y7)  You can see total of users 34, but sum users for landing pages is 39. Does Google analytics website send two requests for this example?

Comment: Your image comes from a report that contained a request with more then just two dimensions. I can see you have cut them off in the picture.    Like i said you need to make the exact same request in the API that you are looking at in the Google analytics Website.    Which means you need to add the other dimensions and metrics in your request to the api if you want to get the same results as that page has.

Comment: It is default report from GA for landing pages and there is only one dimension - landingPagePath [example2](https://prnt.sc/l70s41). My full request with parameters: start-date=DATE1&end-date=DATE2&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3AlandingPagePath&filters=ga%3AchannelGrouping%3D%40Organic 
and I hope to see same result for total of users like in GA website, but it doesn't happen. My question - what parameter do I need to use for result like on screeshot?

Comment: You have again cut off the image what is to the right of users.  Take a picture of the full report.  Or loop up at my answer again.   You need to include every dimension and metric in that report to get the same results as the report.  You cant just take the first two.

Comment: [full screenshot](https://prnt.sc/l715r2) anf full request: start-date=DATE1&end-date=DATE2&metrics=ga:sessions,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:bounceRate,ga:goalCompletionsAll,ga:users&dimensions=ga%3AlandingPagePath&filters=ga%3AchannelGrouping%3D%40Organic

Comment: ga:landingPagePath
ga:users
ga:newUsers
ga:sessions
ga:bounceRate
ga:pageviewsPerSession
ga:avgSessionDuration
ga:goal1ConversionRate
ga:goal1Completions
ga:goal1Value

Comment: remove the filter

Comment: ga:landingPagePath - it is dimension, I can not use it as metric. You can try it in explorer GA https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: I never said you should use that as a metric.  I assumed that you would be able to work out which where dimensions and metrics on your own.